# Do Jpa methods execute with or without transactions by default?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using JPA with hibernate for mysql.

I want to know whether jpa query methods will execute with or without transaction by default.

I am not using transaction management or locking of any sort.

Authoritative reference will be appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-save-saveall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA with hibernate by default uses transaction. to be very precise it uses,
`@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` . If any other `TransactionAttributeType` is not defined explicitly, this  is what you get by default.
To learn more refer to this [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncik/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The individual jpa methods can be transactional, but if your logic uses several of these methods(several read/write operations) and you want them to run as an atomic operation in a multithreaded environment, you would still need to make the logic/method transactional to achieve that.